# Issue with Zen mode in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was comparing two simple graphs I got as the output from a python file(using matplotlib) in VSC 1.59.1. I faced these issues:
-->I can open only one figure of graph from a single file at a time. I cannot run another .py file unless I close the graph for first .py file.
-->So I dragged two files in the form of grid.
-->I Opt for zen mode.
-->And finally tried to run the file in interactive window but in that case I cannot see my other file.
-->So does this mean that I need to opt for split down to see my both the files and their respective graph figure in interactive window ?

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, run one from an ordinary command line, not part of VSC.

Answer (score 0):

Here if you compare two graphs files and see two figures in your interactive window you need to split the terminal and run two python files separately in zen mode.

[Spilt Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TRbV.png)

[Compare two graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4mat.png)

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: But if I split right, I can't see my other file in zen mode. Is there any way to change the position of interactive window in VSC or is there any floating window option for it ?